# How to get last record of duplicate data?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have table `A ( id - message - user_id )`, I need to say if any `user_id` duplicated in table just bring last one that user had added:

My controller code (my wrong shut):

```
$duplicate = VerfiyRequest::where('user_id', '>' , 1)->first();

$VerfiyRequests = VerfiyRequest::latest()->get();

return view('backend.VerfiyRequest.index' , compact('VerfiyRequests'));
```

Comment: Do you want to get the latest VerifyRequest regardless? How about `VerfiyRequest::latest()->first();` ?

Comment: @senty here is the idea: if any user has two or more records in VerfiyRequest table  just bring one of them which is last one of his records

Comment: Doesn't this do the job? `VerfiyRequest::where('user_id', $userId)->latest()->first();`? So you don't need to check about the duplicate at all

Comment: @senty my method is index without parameters!

Comment: So you want to get last model for all users?

Comment: @senty yeah means if user has one Record just bring it or if have two or there records just bring last one that he add it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get the last record of each user by the latest id (incrementing primary key):

```php
VerfiyRequest::whereIn('id', function ($query) {
    $query
        ->from('verify_requests')
        ->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) as id'))
        ->groupBy('user_id');
})->get();
```

Explanation: the `MAX(id) as id` selects latest `id` of each user group, so the inner query returns latest record of each user.

Comment: what is ( $userId ) cuz my method is index without any parameters !

Comment: @ahmed you want to list latest record of each user? or get latest record of a specific user or what?

Comment: Yeah  exactly latest record  of each user without duplicate and parameters cuz it's index method :)

Comment: @ahmed you can try my edited answer, don't forget to replace `verify_requests` with your table name.

Comment: @HafezDivandari yeah man! worked perfectly! could you pls explain what is inside raw() ?